# Quantile given Characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions, quantile-function

For a random variable defined by the PDF $f(x)$ and CDF $F(x)$,

- Characteristic function $CF(x)$ (if it exists) is given by the Fourier transform of $f(x)$.
- Quantile $Q(x)$ (if it exists) is given by the inverse of $F(x)$.

If both $CF(x)$ and $Q(x)$ exists,

1. What is the quantile given the characteristic function?
2. Is there a relationship between the two similar to the inverse function theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic function, say $\varphi$, exists for any real-valued variable, even if multivariate, but I'll stick to the univariate case. But it's a function of a dummy variable typically denoted $t$, not $x$. If the PDF exists, it's$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-itx}\varphi(t)dt.$$More generally, the CDF is$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}\int_{-\infty}^xe^{-itu}du\varphi(t)dt.$$

Comment: I do not see how this answers any of the questions. How do you invert the second integral? and hence get the quantile (this would solve Q1)

Comment: @user400479 Unfortunately, thinking in terms of CDFs, CFs or PDFs all leave quantile calculation equally difficult: you'll just have to calculate $F(x)$, then attempt to invert it.